# Compile PHP5.4 for Apache (PHP5.3 already apt-get installed)

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have had PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1 installed through Ubuntu's `apt-get` for some time.

I now want to install PHP5.4, which I was planning on compiling from source. I have extracted into `/usr/src/php-5.4.3/` and run:

`./configure --with-mysqli --with-pcre-regex --with-pdo-mysql --with-pear --with-curl --with-gd --with-openssl; make; make install`

aswell as `apt-get install`ing other required libs to make that work.

Now `php -v` is 5.4, as expected, but when I use PHP through Apache it still points to 5.3 somehow. I've even done `apt-get remove --purge php5-dev` but I'm missing something.
Any ideas what?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess you're mixing the cli with the dso module. You may include the complied php as an Apache DSO Module, adding the LoadModule directive in your apache conf file (eg httpd.conf)

Comment: @hornetbzz I have `LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load`, but I wouldn't know what to change to make this work. I've made some progress as you can see in the comments for @Mike s question. I'll try what you've just added as an answer though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where you 'll see the steps for that process (looks like you're missing the *apxs2* and the apache *LoadModule* directive in our question) :

```
#!/bin/sh 
 # #################################################### 
 # PHP INSTALLATION SHELL for compiled version
 # By Hornetbzz - 17/09/2010 
 # localhost stands for the machine to be installed 
 # remote host stands for the machine to be duplicated 
 # chmod 700 and run as root 
 # #################################################### 

# ########################
# USER CONTROL
# ########################
[[ $(whoami) != "root" ]] && echo "pls run as root" && exit

# ########################
# SOURCE DIR
# ########################
SRC=/usr/local/src

# ########################
# latest php tarball
# check the most recent mtime tarball in the source directory (already downloaded)
# ########################
LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED=$(ls -t *tar.gz $SRC | head -1)
echo "latest php tarball: $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED"
[[ ! -z $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED ]] && LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED=$SRC/$LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED
echo "latest php tarball (full path): $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED"


# get source files from mirror if no tarball already existing in the src directory
if [ -z $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED ];then
    echo "No php tarball found => it will be downloaded from mirror" && exit
    MIRROR="fr.php.net"
    VERSION="5.3.3"
    cd $SRC
    wget http://$MIRROR/get/php-$VERSION.tar.gz/from/this/mirror
    # tarball checksum : not done
    mv mirror "php-$VERSION.tar.gz"
    # get the last accessed tarball file
    LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED=$SRC/"php-$VERSION.tar.gz"
fi

# name with full path
echo "checkpoint: $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED"

# ########################
# PROCEED to installation
# ########################
 if [ -f $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED ];then

     echo "Local PHP sources : $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED"

     # change directory - keep this even if already done -
     cd $SRC

     # untar
     tar xzf $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED

    # get the new dir name created on the localhost after untar
    echo "basename: " && echo $(basename $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED)
    NEW_DIR_NAME=$(basename $LOCAL_SRC_INSTALLED | sed -e "s/\.tar\.gz$//")

     echo "Info: New src directory created: $NEW_DIR_NAME" 

     # change directory 
     cd /usr/local/src/$NEW_DIR_NAME 

     [[ -f "config.nice ]] && cp config.nice config.nice.original

        # NOTA: copying this shell, you may have to escape each included quote by a backslash, like this \"
         echo -e " 
     # build: import remote host config.nice into the localhost installation shell
    # Created by configure
    './configure' \
    '--prefix=/usr/local/php' \
    '--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2' \
    '--enable-embed' \
    '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/php.ini' \
    '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local' \
    '--with-gd=shared' \         # NOTA: remove "=shared" if you install a bundled lib as explained in my wiki page
     all other options there
    '--enable-mbstring' \
    "$@"
" > config.nice

        make clean
       ./config.nice
    make 
    make install
        echo -e "LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php/lib/libphp5.so \n
                 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php \n
                 PHPIniDir "/usr/local/php \n" >> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

        /etc.init.d/apache2 stop
        /etc.init.d/apache2 start
        /etc.init.d/apache2 reload

else 
    echo "PHP source : local tarball not found in $SRC" 
fi
```

Comment: I can't run that script as is. It throws a few errors, but I do have axps installed now, and there is a `LoadModule` in `mods-enabled` but that itself is throwing an error. This is from Mikes answer `apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: OnUpdateLong`

Comment: sure you can't, this is just to show you the steps. Pls take care apxs is not apxs2. As you have installed the non-threaded-MPM-apache (prefork), the apxs you need is part of the apache2-prefork-dev package, not of apache2-threaded-dev.
apache2-threaded-dev is for the apache running with a multi-threaded MPM (worker).

apt-get remove apache2-threaded-dev

apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev

Comment: Aha! It's working. Mike already prompted me to install `apache2-prefork-dev` but I couldn't see the `apxs` binary until I did `updatedb; locate apxs`. Now I've got the joy of finding all the missing extensions it didn't install. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You installed the command line version only.. You didn't install the apache module. You need to add the following

```
--with-apxs2
```

Make sure you have `apache2-dev` installed

Comment: During the configure I'm getting: Sorry, I cannot run apxs.  Possible reasons follow:

1. Perl is not installed
2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)

Comment: Does this mean I have to compile apache from source or, is there a path to apxs I don't know about (whatever apxs is)?

Comment: what happens if you run `apxs` from command line?

Comment: Command not found. There's an `apxs2` in `apache2-threaded-dev` and `apache2-prefork-dev`

Comment: which version of apache do you have? install that same version for -dev `dpkg -l | grep apache`

Comment: I have `2.2.22 (Ubuntu)` but `dpkg -l | grep apache` also shows `libapache2-mod-php5                    5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1` which could well be the problem. I'm not sure exactly what to install here, excuse my ignorance?

Comment: ok just try installing apache2-prefork-dev and that should clear things up for you

Comment: Thanks. That compiled fine, but when I restart I get a config error. `apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: OnUpdateLong`

Comment: That boils down to `LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so` in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3375/discussion-between-mike-and-adam)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your `httpd.conf` file/dir and take a close look at your `LoadModule` statements. There is bound to be one still pointing towards php 5.3.